# Visual Studio 2017 Community: "Using" suggestions for classes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

I'd like to achieve something similar to what IntelliJ is capable of.
For example, if I type only a part of class' name in IntelliJ I get a list of suggestions for namespaces/packages. If I choose one of them - the class' name get autocompleted and appropriate package name gets added on top with import statement.

Now, when I try to do something similar in Visual Studio 2017 Community, it's a different story. Let's take System.Console class as an example.

- If I type "Cons" and press ctrl+space or alt+enter - I don't get any good suggestions
- If I type "Cons", add "using System" manually and press ctrl+space - I get the System.Console suggestion
- If I type "Conso" and press alt+enter - It basically behaves like IntelliJ - which means it appends the "using System" statement and autocompletes the class' name to Console. The option is the last one though, so I have to scroll through bunch of others (such as generate property, generate local etc.).

My question is - can I make Intellisense behave like in the 3rd case, but

- Make it work for shorter phrases (right now it kind of works for "Conso" but not for anything shorter)
- Make it so I get the "using" suggestions under ctrl+shift menu
- Prioritize the "using" option so it's on the top of the action list

What I tried:

- Enabled "Suggest usings for types (...)" under Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This extension for VS2017 and 2019 seems to do most of what I asked:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dreamescaper.IntelliSenseExtender

Keep in mind that suggestions for non-imported types are not enabled by default. You have to turn them on in: tools -> options -> Intellisense Extender

Comment: Hi, thanks for your sharing and we are glad to hear that your issue is solved, please mark your reply as answer and that will help other to easier search this helpful information, it just a suggestion :)